# how to change th IP of a server Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: networking, 20.04, ip

how to change the IP, Network, Gateway,Broadcast, Netmask and Prefix of a Ubuntu Server 20.04?
I need to change all this and i am not sure which files to change. If i do it wrong, i loose the remote access to this webserver. I do not want to make any mistake.
Can you help me with instructions or pointing me to the right documentation?
Thank you.

**EDIT:**
The file /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml contains this:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens18:
      match:
        macaddress: 
      addresses:
        - x.x.x.x/19
        #- xxx:0000:0001/64
      #gateway6: fe80::1
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: x.x.x.1 
          on-link: true
      nameservers:
        search: [ invalid ]
        addresses:
          - x.x.x.x
          - x.x.x.x
```

I understand how to replace IP (bellow address) but i need help with the remaining items. The prefix is to replace on the /19? The gateway is to place in the routes, via right? But where to place the broadcast and the netmask?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check **.yml** file inside: `/etc/netplan/`.
2. Change value accordingly and keep indentation in mind.
3. Save file and run command `sudo netplan try` and then `sudo netplan apply`.
4. Done

Comment: Thank you. But i still have doubts. I edit the question to post more information. Thank you.